# Java: JLabel не меняет своё положение

Tags: java, swing

Я изучаю графическую библиотеку swing и столкнулся с проблемой - текст не изменяет своё положение относительно jpanel при изменении параметров setVerticalAlignment и setHorizontalAlignment. Я не могу понять, в чём проблема. Скажите пожалуйста, как это исправить.
Вот сам код:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Display extends Java_Panel{
    public static Java_Panel Java_Panel = new Java_Panel();
    public static Java_Frame Java_Frame = new Java_Frame(Java_Panel);
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Java_Panel.ACI_Start(Label_Container.F_Label);
    }
}
public class Java_Frame extends JFrame{
    public Java_Frame(Java_Panel Java_Panel){
        super("DoW");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setUndecorated(true);
        add(Java_Panel);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
public class Java_Panel extends JPanel{
    public Java_Panel(){
        super();
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        add(Label_Container.F_Label);
    }
    public void ACI_Start(Java_Label Java_Label){
        for(int alpha_channel = 0; alpha_channel < 255; alpha_channel++){
            Java_Label.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255, alpha_channel));
            Java_Label.repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(8);
            } catch (InterruptedException InterruptedExpection) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
public class Java_Label extends JLabel{
    public Java_Label(String java_string, Color Color,
                        String Font_Name, int Font_Size){
        super(java_string);
        setForeground(Color);
        setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        setFont(new Font(Font_Name, Font.PLAIN, Font_Size));
    }
}
public class Label_Container{
    static Java_Label F_Label = new Java_Label("Some_Text", new Color(255, 255, 255, 0),
                                        "Arial", 50);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setVerticalAlignment` и `setHorizontalAlignment` насколько я помню, управляют не расположением самого `JLabel` внутри `JPanel`, а расположением **текста внутри `JLabel`**. По умолчанию `JLabel` занимает столько места, сколько в нем текста. То есть, чтобы увидеть действие этих методов, нужно принудительно задать размеры `JLabel` с помощью метода  `setPreferredSize(new Dimansion(100, 100));`
Например, создав, такой `JLabel` внутри функции `main()`

```
 JLabel topLabel = new JLabel("Top");
          topLabel.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
          topLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
          topLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimansion(100, 100));
          topLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1);
          topLebel.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
```

И добавив его на панель, мы должны будем наглядно увидеть такую картину:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если изменить значение метода `setHorizontalAlignment` на `RIGHT`, а `setVerticalAlignment()` оставить как есть, то увидим следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть мы действительно управляем выравниванием текста внутри `JLabel`

Выравнивание самого `JLabel` внутри `JPanel` осуществляется с помощью метода `JPanel.setLayout();` в который передаются специальные объекты. Они называются [менеджеры компоновки](http://www.quizful.net/post/swing-layout-managers).